# Can not set Template of PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, templates, windows-phone

I would like to set template of my PhoneApplicationPage. When I try this code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Template>
```

I get this "xaml" error:

```
4011 An error has occurred.
```

but when I try this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Style>
    <Style TargetType="mpc:PhoneApplicationPage">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>                
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Style>
```

I don't get any errors, but nothing happens.

I'm wondering why I can't set my own template to PhoneApplicationPage.

Thx for answers.

***Note**: I have BaseFormPage, which should use this template and other derived pages will be different in content, but the template will be the same, derived from BaseFormPage.*

Comment: Have you tried to generate the template in Blend? Usually Blend does it right and you can fine tune in VS.